# How does one connect to an SSH server?

Tags: ssh, fedora, website

I am not familiar with SSH. I am attempting to run a website, and I am used to receiving FTP-information. However, this time, I was simply told to "connect through SSH." How do I go about doing this? In particular, how does one connect to an SSH-server in Fedora 20? I do have all the login information needed.

Comment: how are you connecting through ftp?

Comment: Normally, I'd just use FileZilla with the information provided by the host. In this case, I have attempted sftp://host.host.com, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Putty is a good place to start. Alternatively (or in addition to), [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) will help you maintain that FTP/Explorer view you're probably used to, and if you're not trying to learn command lines. WinSCP will requires Windows, and you can use this to connect to any SSH server.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading files you could use [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) as a client and use it like any other FTP programme.

To set it up, first click on the *Site Manager* button (1) and enter the details provided by your administrator. Make sure to select *SFTP* as the protocol (3) and 22 as the port (4). Change *Logon Type* to *Normal* (5) and enter your username (6) and password (7).

Finally, click *Connect* and you should see your remote host's file system.

[image: Screenshot of FileZille Setup]

Comment: I already have FileZilla, but I am unable to see how it is to be used for SSH-servers.

Comment: When creating new connections, it's possible to specify a connection type.

SSH (here) is synonymous to SFTP, so you can select that.

Comment: Okay. The admin simly said this: "You can access add files through SSH at host.host.com. with your regular username and password." If I cannot connect to sftp://host.host.com through FileZilla, the error is with the host, correct?

Comment: I have updated my answer above to include a short tutorial and screenshot. If you're sure you've entered everything correctly, it might be possible that there's a problem with the host. To be sure, we'd need to know the exact error message.

Comment: SFTP is not necessarily enabled with ssh . . . it's configured via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: I will attempt this as soon as I get my computer back.

Comment: I simply get "No route to host."

Comment: Make sure you typed the host part correctly. If that doesn't work, get in touch with your administrator again.